# How to change Uptick Increments in HTML Number Input

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input

I have a number input form:

```
<input type='number' id='select-number'>Pick A number
```

I have the following questions:

1: The default uptick increment is 1 (when you click the up arrow on the number input, it goes up by a value of one per click.) How can I change that? I want it to go up in values of 0.1 (tenths). How do I do that?

2: Secondly, I have two variables:

```
feet=true;
meters=false;
```

One will always be true, and the other false. How do I change the "max" attribute (using Javascript) based on which of these two variables is true? The two variables come from code something like this:

```
<input type='radio' id='feet' name='unit_of_measurement'>Feet
<input type='radio' id='meters' name='unit_of_measurement'>Meters
<script>
feet=document.getElementById('feet').checked;
meters=document.getElementById('meters').checked;
</script>
```

If the variable "feet" is true, then the maximum value of the input (Id='select-number') needs to be 3. If it is meters, it needs to be 8.

How can I do that(^), and how can I change the uptick increment? Thanks for any help.

NOTE: Vanilla Javascript only, Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) To change the step of an input simply use `step=".1"` inside the `input` tag.

2) To change the max on radio change add a `onchange="change()"` which sets the max and/or step based on which is checked

html

```
<input type='radio' id='feet' name='unit_of_measurement' onchange="change()" checked>Feet
<input type='radio' id='meters' name='unit_of_measurement' onchange="change()">Meters
```

js

```
function change() {
  feet = document.getElementById('feet').checked;
  meters = document.getElementById('meters').checked;
  selectNumber = document.getElementById('select-number');
  if (feet) {
      selectNumber.max = 300;
      selectNumber.step = 1;
  } else {
      selectNumber.max = 100;
      selectNumber.step = .3;
  }
};
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrykmp8/) or [fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/se93mu9z/1/)

Comment: Edited to optimize the code and upvoted for complete answer

Answer (score 0):

The default uptick increment can be modified by using `step` attribute

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" step="0.1">
```

and any property can be accessed (set and get) by getting handle of DOM element.

```
oldValue = document.getElementById('#<id>').propertyName;  //get
document.getElementById('#<id>').propertyName = newValue;  //set
```

Comment: Thanks. There were two questions, though.

Comment: you seems to know `checked` so same way you can use other properties `document.getElementById().checked = true`

Comment: the edit wasn't totally necessary, but whatever. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: yeah. Personally I don't see it making a huge difference, but every bit helps, I guess.

Comment: does being edited give rep, or does editing give rep?

Comment: k. It says can continue discussion in chat if u want